# my site is showing me integrity error something regarding POST

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACghb.png)[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1xzL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aICfo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kday.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Htm6.png)

i am facing this error and i am currently new to django and don't know how to overcome it i have pasted the error page and the page of my contact form

i wanted to save the information that i get by filling the form to be saved in my data base/admin

Comment: Can i see your contact model?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I guess it's actually easier to copy and paste your codes/errors here than to include them as image or links.

Comment: Also please include your forms.py so we can also see that

Comment: Also, don't post the code as images next time. Just post the code like ```  code ``` .

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save a contact without a name. If you want to all that use below code.

```
name = models.CharField(max_length = 200,blank=True,null=True)
```

`blank=True` means allowing empty value in form.

`null=True` means allowing empty values in DB.